# Insert code when users come from an specific referer

Tags: php, posts, redirect

Let me elaborate, because I think this is a pretty strange question.

I want to be able to add some code to my post when a user comes from an specific referrer and arrives to an specific URL.

This will only happen in one specific URL like `myweb.com/addcode` so when the user gets there the following process will be triggered:

1. It will check the referrer
2. If the referrer matches, the user will be redirected to a random post and the code will be added.
3. If not, the user will just be redirected to a random post.

I’ve already work my way around the referrer check and the random post redirection:

**Random Redirection.**

Searching through stackoverflow i found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672401/get-random-post-in-wordpress) where they give some great solutions for showing random posts.

**Referrer.**

In order to check the referrer I'm using wp_get_referer()

```
$referer = wp_get_referer();
if (  strpos($referer ,'http://wanteddomain.com') !== false )
```

So I'm left to find a clean way to "insert" code to my posts preferably just at the start of body.

I want to be able to add some   and pure html code but I have not been able to find info related to the topic (I'm surely using the wrong wording).

Any help or direction about what or where to research would be greatly appreciated!

And thank you for taking your time reading this non-sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post does make sense, you just want to change/add some content based on referrer, which is very common among websites.

Now, as you asked just at the start of body. I don't believe there is any standard hook in there, other than `get_header();`. This function is usually located at the very beginning of most of the template files.

The common structure of a single post is something like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    // Some content
<?php get_sidebar(); // If your theme has a sidebar ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So you should be able to hook into this and output your content. This goes into your theme's `functions.php` or a plugin:

```
add_action('get_header', 'my_referrer_check');
function my_referrer_check () {
    $referer = wp_get_referer();
    if (  strpos($referer ,'http://wanteddomain.com') !== false ){
        // The rest of your code here
    }
}
```

This will automatically add your code to the `get_header` action hook.

The other solution is to wrap your code in a function and use that function inside your template, wherever you wish:

```
function my_referrer_check () {
    $referer = wp_get_referer();
    if (  strpos($referer ,'http://wanteddomain.com') !== false ){
        // The rest of your code here
    }
}
```

Now by using `my_referrer_check();` you can get your content anywhere.

### Some handy functions

In the path of conquering your adventure, you might need some allies. These functions might serve you well, at the time of needs:

- To redirect a user : `wp_redirect('URL-HERE');` or
  `wp_safe_redirect('URL-HERE');` followed instantly by a `die();` or
  `exit();`
- To check whether you are on a single post or any where else on your
  templates: `is_single()`, `is_page()`, `is_home()`, etc.
- To get the query parameters: `get_query_var('paremeter-here');`

Comment: I agree. One thing to keep in mind is that referrer is often missing or even easily spoofed. This means that visitors from your special referrer may reach your site without the referrer field; and you won't be able to treat them specially. This also means that others (not coming from your special referrer) may be able to pass off as if they did. 
You should use this logic only if the consequences are not a big deal.

Comment: Certainly. This is useful when trying to something simple, like showing a tech news to some user who has landed from some nerdy technology website.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Jack Johansson and sorry for the delayed answer. That was just what I needed. And thank you Sas3 for the insight about spoofing, I'll keep that in mind.